# How to validate form without entity in controller?

Tags: php, forms, validation, symfony

I have a basic form to send an email :

```
<form action="{{ path('user_send_mail') }}" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">

  <input name="email_to" type="email" class="form-control" placeholder="To" required>

  <input name="email_cc" type="email" class="form-control" placeholder="Cc">

  <textarea name="message" id="email_message" class="form-control" placeholder="message"     style="height: 120px;" required></textarea>

  <input type="file" name="attachment"/>

  <p class="help-block">Max. 2MB</p>

  <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary pull-left"><i class="fa fa-envelope"></i> Send the email</button>

</form>
```

And an action in my controller to validate the data and send the mail but validation doesn't work..

```
use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints\Email;
use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints\File;
use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints\NotBlank;

public function sendMailToUserAction(Request $request)
{
        $form = $this->createFormBuilder(null)
            ->add('email_to', 'email', array(
                'required' => true,
                'constraints' => new Email()
            ))
            ->add('email_cc', 'email', array(
                'required' => false,
                'constraints' => new Email()
            ))
            ->add('message', 'textarea', array(
                'required' => true,
                'constraints' => new NotBlank()
            ))
            ->add('attachment', 'file', array(
                'required' => false,
                'constraints' => new File()
            ))
            ->getForm();

        $form->handleRequest($request);

        if ($form->isValid()) {
            $data = $form->getData();
            var_dump($data);exit;
        } else {
            var_dump("error");exit;
        }
}
```

When I submit the form, I got always "error", so validation doesn't work but I don't know why... I have read a lot of topics about this but I get stuck..

**EDIT :** If I print form error using `$form->getErrorsAsString()` instead of `var_dump("error");exit;`, I got this :

```
string(97) "email_to: No errors email_cc: No errors message: No errors attachment: No errors "
```

Comment: You have to fill required fields before submitting. Please be more concise in what you tried and what does not work.

Comment: I have fill required fields before submitting but form is not validated, var_dump("error") is called

Comment: Symfony's [Form component](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/blob/2.4/src/Symfony/Component/Form/Form.php) has a `getErrors()` method - var dump that and it should shed some more light on what's wrong.

Comment: try printing $form->getErrorsAsString() and show us the output

Comment: I try it, look at my question please I edited it

Comment: Looking through the source of Form, it would suggest the problem is the form has not been submitted. You need to call [`$form->submit()`](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/blob/2.4/src/Symfony/Component/Form/Form.php#L496). Validation will always fail if `$form->submitted` is false, and it only sets this tracking variable to true inside `submit()`.

Comment: If I use `$form->submit($request->request->get($form->getName()));` instead of `$form->handleRequest($request);` I got this errror : "The CSRF token is invalid. Please return the form."

Comment: Symfony docs suggests handleRequest is perfectly ok to use. But that doesn't explain why your form was invalid before.

Comment: huum.. if I `var_dump($form->handleRequest($request));` I got all the informations entered in my form.. but I can't validate them...

Answer (score 0):

please reffer to this: http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/forms.html#using-a-form-without-a-class it think you have to pass array with fields name that you want to validate (its like a default values)

p. s. why not using Simple PHP Object for that? Symfony2 forms fields name should contain brakets like (for example): data[email_to] instead of email_to